# After changing package name I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I started a small Java project on Eclipse with two classes that are in the *(default package)*.
Everything is working fine but when I tried to create a new package (let's say net.server) with the same two classes (with the package name statement in each one) I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClassName
```

I'm not experienced with Java and Eclipse and I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Is everything that you moved now in the same package? Did you perform all your moves using the Eclipse refactor menu? Was it done as one move or multiple?

Comment: Yes, everything is in the same package now. I created a new project and copied the two classes manually. Eclipse doesn't show any warnings or errors with the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try to delete the old run configuration: from the menu select *Run* > *Run Configurations*, find your config on the left hand side, select it and click the delete button above it, finally re-run your application.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't update your imports in your main file (the one who runs the `main` method). `ClassNotFoundException` implies that the classloader couldn't find a certain class given the current directives.

Eclipse should be sending you a warning about this (underlining the offending imports in red). To organize the imports for a given file directly, use the `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `O` shortcut while editing it.

Answer (score 1):

**<strike>Never</strike>** **Recommended not to** use the *default package*. As a standard, the root package is named after your project (e.g. If project is **net.server.project**, then the root package has the same name)

Beware that Eclipse has issues with **Move refactoring** (I don't know if this is fixed in Kepler 4.3)

Since you only have two classes, I would recommend you created the two classes from scratch, and manually copied the functionality from the old ones into the new ones. This is the safest way to ensure that everything is in order.

Oh, and I hope your **src** folder is a **source folder**, and not a regular one.

Comment: I wouldn't say Never, it's ok to do it as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: It's all about aesthetics.

Comment: Everything has a propose, you can use it in a good way for what it was made for, or you can screw things up with it. This apply to everything in the Java language (and the other languages). So again, saying never here is wrong. I would replace it with a (recommend).
Here is what Oracle says:"Unnamed packages are provided by the Java platform principally for convenience when developing small or temporary applications or when just beginning development."